# RESTAPI in AngularJS - Does calling a GET Route always cause a new connection to be established?

Tags: angularjs, rest, get

I would like to know if you call several GET Routes in AngularJS via a RESTAPI, if for each GET a new connection is established or if it's just one connection with several "underconnections" (Threads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes every Ajax call opens a new connection. A browser can't just do multiple threads under one connection for Ajax purposes because multiple connections can come from different sources. But now with HTTP/2 your initial connection has the potential to come along one pipe. You can potentially open a websocket and funnel traffic down a single pipe but that isn't Ajax.